# How would I go about preventing the user from going into nonexistent records in a database (Visual basic 6.0 using Microsoft DAO 2.5/3.51)

Tags: vb6, dao

Firstly, I am using visual basic 6 because that is what my school teaches.
We are meant to do a practice project for a supposed client that wants a program that allows employees to interact with a database.
I have made the First, prev,next and last button for record navigation, however, the issue is that the user is allowed beyond existing records using prev or next and it crashes the program with the error that there is no value

I have tried things like:
Making 2 counters, one for the current record that you are on and one for how many records are in the selected recordset. What I thought it would do is that if your current record tries to surpass the recordcount, it will cancel the action, but in the end the recordset.recordcount always returned 1 or 0 for some reason

I have also tried testing for if the primary key field is blank, but it returns the error that there is no such record

So how would I go about limiting the user from going beyond the records?

Comment: Check the recordset .BOF and .EOF values to see if you're at the start or end of the recordset and act accordingly.

Comment: Whew, DAO huh?  Seems like an odd choice considering that one of the things VB6 was all about was integrating ADO to replace the older technologies.

Comment: @JohnEason I have figured it out and BOF and EOF checks only if you are outside of the file not if you are still in it and at the beginning/end.

Answer (score -1):

In the end, I was able to use an error handler for my problem to handle the error of the user trying to go beyond existing records.

What I did was:

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandler 'If any error happens go to ErrHandler

recordset.movenext 
setFields 'Subroutine for setting the text boxes to their values

ErrHandler:
recordset.movelast 'If the user tries to go beyond the last record move him back
```

Update 2: I have also tried using the BOF and EOF people have been saying in the comments. I first had some confusion regarding them because I thought these properties were checking if it was the first record or the last record, but actually it was checking if you were outside of the file.

```
recordset.movenext 'move to the next record
If recordset.EOF = True Then 'If the user is outside the file
    recordset.moveprevious 'Move him back
Else 'If he is not
    setFields 'Set the fields
End If 'End the if
```

This is much simpler than the error handler.

Comment: No need to use an error handler. As I said in my last comment, just use .BOF or .EOF to check whether you're at the beginning or end of the recordset **before** allowing the user to move to the next or previous record!

Comment: Yes.  Often that's as simple as `CommandNN.Enable = Not .EOF` for forward moves and `Not .BOF` for backward moves right after completing the move.

Comment: To [the reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29325377): Why would you recommend deleting this answer? It's the OP posting what worked for them, providing the code they used.